# Отложенная загрузка скрипта

Tags: javascript, vue.js, scripts

я хочу сделать подключение  vue компонента через id на странице с подключаемым скриптом. Что-то типо этого

```
.cell.cell-xl-8
    #app-cart(data-url="http://localhost:3000/products")
          script.
            window.onload = function() {
              import {createApp} from "vue";
              import App from "./app-cart.vue";
              import store from "./vuex/store.js";

              let cartApp = document.querySelector("#app-cart");

              if (cartApp) {
                createApp(App, { props: ["data-url"] }).use(store).mount("#app-cart");
              }
            };
```

но при загрузке в консоли

> Cannot use import statement outside a module

если я добавляю скрипту атрибут type="module", то следующая ошибка в консоли

> Unexpected identifier

если мне вынести все import в общий файл `index.js`, который подключается `webpackom` в конец страницы,  то он не может инициализировать `createApp`. Тогда как сделать отложенную загрузку для этого скрипта? Подскажите, я в тупике

Comment: вебпаком через точку входа все бандлы подключаются, так наиболее перспективно в плане отсутствия ошибок.

Comment: тогда другой вопрос, как мне сделать отложенную загрузку скрипта, в случае если бэкенд подключает все скрипты в head страницы?

Comment: для отложенного взаимодействия с бекэндом используйте async/await, с обязательной обработкой ошибок в .catch.